# Cant do a GET request with Fetch API against Django REST Framework - HTTP 304 error

Tags: javascript, express, http, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

Im trying to do a GET request against Django REST API with Fetch API (Node Fetch) module. But I encounter an error 304 when Im doing the GET request. I have no idea how to approach it. Ive read about it that its about requesting the same data as before. Can this not be possible to do? Or how do I store this information somehow?

This is my code of a controller in Express.js:

```
postsController.index = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let postsResponse = fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/posts.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(res)
        })

        postsResponse.then((result) => {
            res.render('newspapers/index', { title: 'Posts', posts: result })
        })
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
express_1  |     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
express_1  |     at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
express_1  |     at ServerResponse.contentType (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:595:15)
express_1  |     at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:145:14)
express_1  |     at done (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
express_1  |     at Object.exports.render (/var/www/app/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:206:5)
express_1  |     at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/var/www/app/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:233:13)
express_1  |     at View.render (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
express_1  |     at tryRender (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
express_1  |     at Function.render (/var/www/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
```

I tried go to network tab on Chrome and select "disable cache" and now i get 200 OK, but I still get a traceback of that problem above for some reason. What does that mean?

Comment: small nitpick #1, `.catch(err => next(err))`. small nitpick #2, "Content-Type": "application/json" , I believe, is not needed in GET requests. To your question, it seems another handler has sent a response, before the `res.render` function. Without inspecting the entire app, it's hard to pinpoint where the error might be.

Comment: @pandamakes Thanks for the comment. I tried using curL to do a GET request, and it works. So it definetly in the expressjs code. Why can I do many GET requests with curL and not in the code? Because the error 304 is to get the same data without it has changed right?

Comment: are  you `curl http://localhost:8000/api/posts.json` ? I have no doubt that endpoint works as expected. I suspect it is how the `postsController` is mounted, and how the rest of the express look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors in the >300 range are redirection related.

redirect: 'follow

therefore you should probably follow your redirect or if this redirect behaviour is not intended then you've miss-configured something in your downstream service.

```
        let postsResponse = fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/posts.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
+++         redirect: 'follow'
        })
``
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and I still get the 304 error response. I have updated the question with error output.